# Warning: Expression following 'return' is treated as an argument of the 'return'

Tags: swift, warnings, compiler-warnings

I get this warning in my code and I can't figure out what it means and what I need to do to fix it.
The warning says the following:

> Expression following 'return' is treated as an argument of the 'return'

And it's shown on this line:

```
// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? See code part below.

Some background info, the code is part of a database manager class which I use to migrate a unencrypted realm database to an encrypted one, if the encrypted db doesn't exist yet.
If the encrypted db already exists, it configures realm to use this one as default. If it cannot open it (e.g. because of wrong encryption key) it creates a new database.

```
let exists = self.encryptedDatabaseExists(config)
if exists {
    //Try to open Realm with new config. If unsuccessful, it needs to be removed and a new one created
    do {
        _ = try RLMRealm(configuration: config)

        // Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
        RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
        RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    } catch let err {
        Log.error("Encrypted DB could not be opened: \(err)")
        self.createNewEncryptedDatabase(config)
    }
} else {
    self.migrateToEncryptedDatabase(config)
}
```

Comment: What is the context?  Is this in a function?  That `_ = try ...` looks a little strange to me...

Comment: Change to `let _ = try RLMRealm(configuration: config)`

Comment: @ryantxr No need for that. The wildcard pattern doesn't need "var" or "let". But I don't see why OP uses a wildcard pattern here anyway...

Comment: @nhgrif, first of all thanks for the edits ;) Yes, it's in a function. I use the wildcard _ because I don't use the result of the realm initializer, it's just a check if the given config param can be used to open a realm. If I remove that wildcard I get an extra warning saying 'Result of initializer is unused'.

Comment: TIL using `_` without `let` or `var`...

Comment: Can you try to make an MVCE?  Something I could paste into a playground and still get the error?  (Which will mean taking out the call into 3rd party frameworks, as a start.)

Comment: While creating an MVCE I cleaned my project and deleted derived data - just for the heck of it - and this somehow seemed to help. The warning is gone now. I guess it was some cache issue.

Comment: is this inside a function? can you include the full scope?

Answer (score 10):

Swift 5 
Easy way enjoy it

```
//MARK:- Use it like function its will work
return()
```

Answer (score 1):

NB: Adding this here since I've encountered the issue before.

According to the [swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID444), if an expression follows immediately after the return statement, it will be returned/run as well.

In this case there's a return statement followed by other code expressions that gets treated as an argument.

To prevent this just add a `;` after the return and code execution will stop.

```
return;
```